# How add data to existing records in table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a table like

```
user_id | settings
```

settings stored in json format like

```
{"user_lang":"en","shop_name":"PayBot"}
```

I need to add data like `"user_id: 1"` to each settings record.

In result it have to like this

```
{"user_lang":"en","shop_name":"PayBot","user_id: 1"}
```

How I understand I gave to open each record, encode to array, push to array `"user_id: 1"` and save.

But how to do this in php? :)

Can anybody to provide me a short example?

Thanks!:)

Comment: As questions go, this one is a little too broad for SO **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort on your behalf to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being asked. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by different ways. One way is with `JSON_SET`.

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
   set settings = JSON_SET(settings, "$.user_id", 1) 
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

You can remove the condition and add the column name `user_id` in place of static value **1** to apply all rows for settings column with their corresponding `user_id` value

**REF.:** https://database.guide/json_set-insert-or-update-values-in-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: Thank you, Always Sunny. All ingenious is simple:)

Comment: @AlexB glad it helps you somehow :)